# What is the seamless way to build an IoT application?

Tags: web-applications, iot, intel-galileo

I need to build a lighting control system. I'll use an Arduino and a light sensor to acquire data and a remote app to do the processing and control. I could do this locally within Arduino or with a client/server app using my notebook. But I want to build my app on the cloud, receiving data from Arduino and sending back the action (i.e. increase or decrease light according to the amount of natural light).

What would be the best approach to building this?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it by just coding your arduino sketch, would be using [Muzzley](https://muzzley.com/documentation).

The app itself controls many IoT products available on market but there are also available libs for custom integrations such as Arduino. You'd be able to control your bulb using iOS, Android or even Windows phone.

In the Arduino, you just need to develop your sketch using the muzzley arduino library or a simple MQTT client. Regarding the interface, you can develop it with html/css/js in the website.

Besides controlling your bulb remotely, you can use it together with IoT devices available on market

You can find a similar integration [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1HL9QZI-as)

Answer (score 0):

[Cumulocity](http://www.cumulocity.com) provide a cloud service for visualisation and controlling of IoT data. We provide REST APIs that allows to send light sensor data and a push interface that allows you control the "relay".

Visualisation Web UI comes for free. Controlling a relay (switch) is described  in the [Sensor Library](http://www.cumulocity.com/guides/reference/sensor-library/)
See http://www.cumulocity.com/guides/rest/hello-rest/ for a simple example.